# Track Row for the Prepared Statement Sqlite Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have created a Prepared statement to get the row where my track_id is present. Since I am a beginner I am having problem understanding how can I get values from the whole row one by one
my code is:

```
 public SQLiteStatement retrieveData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("Select * from tracking where track_id= ?");
        return stmt;
```

```
SQLiteStatement statement = db.retrieveData();
                statement.bindString(1,track_data.getText().toString());
                statement.execute()
```

Just like in SQL database we use ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(); How can I store statement.execute() in a variable to get the row details?

Answer (score 0):

In short you don't use **SQLiteStatement**, it's only intended for/(capable of) returning a single column of a single row as per :-

> Represents a statement that can be executed against a database. The
>   statement cannot return multiple rows or columns, but single value (1
>   x 1) result sets are supported.
>   [SQLiteStatement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement)

Instead you'd use :-

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor csr = db.query("tracking",null /* all columns aka */","track_id=?",new String[]{track_data.getText().toString()},null,null,null);
while (csr.moveToNext()) {
    // and for each column value you wanted
    my_value = csr.get??????(csr.getColumnIndex(the_column_name_as_a_string)); 
    // e.g. another my_other_value = csr.get??????(csr.getColumnIndex(the_column_name_as_a_string));
}
```

- ?????? represents many of the methods e.g. getInt, getLong .........
- see [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor)

Or alternately instead of using the convenience method **query**, you could use the **rawQuery** method e.g.

```
Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("Select * from tracking where track_id= ?",new String[]{track_data.getText().toString()});
```